# Display live output of PHP shell_exec in HTML scroll box

Tags: php, html, scrollbar, shell-exec

I have a web interface with two buttons "Ipconfig" and "ping google" which will each display the output of cmd with the appropriate command. Apart from that, I also have a scroll box which currently contains random posts. when the button is clicked, the output of cmd will appear under the scroll box, which can be seen in the image below.

[image: web interface]

how to make the output from cmd (based on which button is clicked) can be displayed in the scroll box (replacing the random text)?

Here is the body of the HTML (not including styling in css):

```
<body>

<h1 style="color:green;">
    Example of PHP Script in HTML
</h1>

<h4>
    The following button displays the command prompt output via php "shell_exec" in the box below
</h4>

<div class="myBox">
    Efficient honorificabilitudinitatibus cross-media information without floccinaucinihilipilification cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas plenipotentiary. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem ratione possimus quos eius rerum totam pariatur vero voluptatum, aspernatur officiis tempora minus nam earum nobis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias sed tempore distinctio commodi, ipsa eius reprehenderit necessitatibus sunt qui doloremque voluptatum dolor, explicabo ea, exercitationem culpa. Facilis quidem placeat quos. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia optio eum ut nam omnis laudantium, delectus harum officia placeat, tempora aspernatur laborum culpa soluta totam sit nulla adipisci, vel sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione facilis nihil suscipit eum tempore quae in culpa alias nostrum repudiandae, nam accusamus! Tempore unde at eveniet aperiam. Tenetur voluptatem magni, sit tempora sequi nemo vitae. Accusantium dolore unde illo fugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque modi adipisci deserunt sequi ab vitae esse veritatis laudantium minus cupiditate. Nobis alias assumenda provident blanditiis ullam, ex ad. Voluptatibus explicabo sequi quae esse eveniet, possimus expedita consectetur suscipit velit ducimus?
</div>

<!-- script php for cmd-->
<?php
    $out1=shell_exec('ipconfig/all');
    $out2=shell_exec('ping google.com');

    if(isset($_POST['button1'])) {
        echo '<pre>'.$out1.'</pre>';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['button2'])) {
        echo '<pre>'.$out2.'</pre>';
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" class="button" value="Ipconfig"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button2" class="button" value="ping google"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: **1)** Just move your `<?php ... ?>` section inside your `<div class="myBox">`.
**2)** Don't run the `shell_exec()` if it's not trigged. Move it in your `if () { ... }` statements to run them only for the appropriate POST action.
**3)** You cannot just print print the output like that because it may contain some chars such as `<` or `>` which will have an HTML meaning. Do `echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($out1) . "</pre>\n";` instead to escape these chars. **4)** Did you want the result to display without reloading the page or not? (normal POST or Ajax request)

Comment: Just as a reminder, *stackoverflow* isn't a platform to solve your exercices. Your question really looks like a student exercice. There's quite a lot of other remarks to do on your code, such as the inline CSS or the names of your buttons, etc. I prefer not to give you the full correct answer as you will learn better if you try to solve the exercice yourself. I gave you some tips above. Show us what you have done after these changes.